# getting undefined when passing prop to parent component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am learning react and I have two components, `Counter.jsx` and `Counters.jsx`. I have a button in my `Counter.jsx` and a method called `onDelete` set on the `onClick` function. I am still working on the onDelete code but I would like to see what button is being deleted when I click delete. For now I have it so that when I click the `delete button`, it will show which button `id` is being deleted. For some reason I keep getting undefined when I check in my chrome console. I will put the code down below.

```js
class Counters extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 2 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]
  };

  handleDelete = counterId => {
    console.log("Event handler called", counterId);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counters.map(counters => (
          <Counter
            key={counters.id}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
            value={counters.value}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}
        className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing in the `id` as a prop to the `Counter` component.

If you add that is will work fine.

```js
<Counter
  key={counters.id}
  id={counters.id}
  onDelete={this.handleDelete}
  value={counters.value}
/>
```

```js
class Counters extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [
      { id: 1, value: 2 },
      { id: 2, value: 0 },
      { id: 3, value: 0 },
      { id: 4, value: 0 }
    ]
  };

  handleDelete = counterId => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      counters: prevState.counters.filter(c => c.id !== counterId)
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.counters.map(counters => (
          <Counter
            key={counters.id}
            id={counters.id}
            onDelete={this.handleDelete}
            value={counters.value}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Counter extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={() => this.props.onDelete(this.props.id)}
        className="btn btn-danger btn-sm m-2"
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Counters />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: can i ask you another quick question @Tholle

Comment: @jsilva Sure, I might be able to answer. If not, it might be a good idea to open up a new question.

Comment: for my delete method i set a new variable called counters equal to the filtered array of the old counters and check where the id is not the same and then I update the state. But when i delete it it's not doing any deletion.

Comment: @jsilva Did you try the `Show code snippet` in my answer?

Comment: Yes that solved the problem of showing the id when the button is clicked for deletion but for the actual deletion is what I am trying to do now. I can open another question and then you can take a look if thats better.